# How to get a list of users from Slack API using BotKit?

Tags: javascript, bots, slack-api, slack, botkit

I'm trying to create a bot that sends a direct message to a random slack user. The first step I am trying to accomplish is console.logging the list of users.

Here is what I have so far:

```
controller.hears('marco', 'direct_message', function(bot, message) {
  bot.api.users.list({user: message.user}, function(err, list){
    bot.reply(message, "polo");
    console.log(bot.api.users.list);
  })
});
```

When I direct message the bot `marco`, it replies `polo` and `[Function]` is logged. How am able to log some real data? I tried `bot.api.users.list.members`, but it logs as `undefined`. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to list ALL users, you are using a correct API call, just remove the params from it (`{}` instead of `{user: message.user}`). 
[Docs: users.list](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list)

If you want to get information about a specific user from your team, you should use the following API call: `bot.api.users.info({ user: USER_ID }, function (err, response) { ... });`
[Docs: users.info](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.info)

There's also a test section in the Slack docs ('Tester' tab) so that you can try out what the API calls will return for your actual users.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just tried removing the params from the API call, but all that still outputs in the console is `[Function]`

Comment: That is because you are trying to console log a function (`bot.api.users.list`) the same one that you are calling two lines above. Instead try logging `list` from the callback.

Comment: @TomiS I am trying to use 
bot.api.users.list((error, response) => {
        console.log(response);
      })
terminal showing its call but didn't get any response even bot.api.users.info is working fine, is there any mistake ?

Comment: @DeepakPatidar try using this API call: bot.api.users.list({ }, (error, response) => { console.log(response) })